# Bootstrap v4 Installation - Initial build & running grunt - aborted due to warnings

Tags: gruntjs, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

Multiple clean installation attempts, plenty of restarts, still frustrated. Sorry if some of these are newb-ish questions.

Following this very succinct guide, I have completed the tooling setup:

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/build-tools/#tooling-setup

alas, my first grunt command pukes at scsslint:

```
Running "scsslint:src" (scsslint) task
Running scss-lint on src
scss/_custom-forms.scss:133 [W] PropertySortOrder: Properties should be ordered
display, max-width, padding, padding-right, vertical-align, background, background-image, background-size, border, -moz-appearance, -webkit-appearance, appearance
scss/_custom-forms.scss:134 [W] Indentation: Line should be indented with spaces, not tabs
scss/_custom-forms.scss:148 [W] PropertySortOrder: Properties should be ordered border-color, outline, box-shadow
scss/_dropdown.scss:56 [W] PropertySortOrder: Properties should be ordered display, width, padding, clear, font-weight, line-height, color, text-align, white-space, background, border
scss/_forms.scss:269 [W] PropertySortOrder: Properties should be ordered padding-right, background-repeat, background-position, background-size
scss/_input-group.scss:100 [W] Shorthand: Shorthand form for property padding should be written more concisely as $input-padding-x-lg instead of $input-pad ding-x-lg $input-padding-x-lg
scss/_labels.scss:44 [W] PropertySortOrder: Properties should be ordered padding-right, padding-left, border-radius
scss/_list-group.scss:51 [W] PropertySortOrder: Properties should be ordered width, color, text-align
scss/_modal.scss:29 [W] PropertySortOrder: Properties should be ordered transition, transform
scss/_navbar.scss:73 [W] PropertySortOrder: Properties should be ordered float,padding-top, padding-bottom, margin-right, font-size
scss/_navbar.scss:93 [W] PropertySortOrder: Properties should be ordered float,width, padding-top, padding-bottom, margin-right, margin-left, overflow
scss/_navbar.scss:98 [W] StringQuotes: Prefer double-quoted strings
scss/_type.scss:179 [W] PropertySortOrder: Properties should be ordered margin-bottom, line-height
scss/_utilities-spacing.scss:43 [W] PropertySortOrder: Properties should be ordered padding-right, padding-left
Warning: Task "scsslint:src" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem. The default task invokes `grunt test` as well which actually fails. Use `grunt dist` instead for building.